# How do i get my password hash $string from my signup file to login file without session or file include

Tags: php, password-hash

Guys I have password verify in my login file

```
if($row['user_name'] === $name &&  password_verify($pass,password_hash $string)) {
```

But I have password hash in my signup modal.php how do I import the $password string which have password hash from signup file to login if I include the signup file it takes the full form at here for signup and the session some guys reffered me to not use session on password
I wanna know how will I get the password hash string to my login file from.signup without session or file include

Comment: The hashed password is the string you should be storing in your database along with the user name which it is associated with.

Comment: Yes it is storing hashed pass by signup file but for password verify i have to take the password hash variable into login file

Comment: Which I cannot take by including signup file as the function break

Comment: And also it doesn't work with storing the hash password variable in a session

Comment: `for password verify i have to take the password hash variable into login file `....you do that by selecting it from the correct row in the database. Obviously in 99% of login scenarios it would not work to use the session because the user would not have visited the sign-up page in the same session, so it makes no sense to even think of doing it like that.

Comment: Oh ok do I have to select the hashed password ya if I'm not mistaking @adyson

Comment: Yes you do. And you can use the username that the user enters into the login form to find the right row in the database

Comment: P.s. did it not occur to you that users would mostly log in without visiting the signup page first? You only sign up once but you can log in many many times after that

Comment: Yes but how will I do the password find by username is there any tutorial @ADyson

Comment: It's a simple SELECT query with a WHERE clause. If you're not experienced with SQL then take some classes